# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'on facebook accesstoken.class

Tags: android, gradle

I have been having some issues with this for a while

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/facebook/AccessToken$1.class

I do not know what to do, please help.

this is my build gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23"

```
aaptOptions {
    useNewCruncher false
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.dell.treblemusic"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}



packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

dexOptions {
    incremental true
}
```

}

dependencies {
   // compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/clink210.jar')
    compile files('libs/eventbus-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile project(':PayPalAndroidSDK-2.12.4')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-java:1.37.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile project(':VisaCheckout-Android-SDK-2.9')
    compile files('libs/card-io-5.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-volley-1.0.10.jar')
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.0'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')
    compile files('libs/guava-13.0.1.jar')
    compile project (':facebook-android-sdk-4.10.0')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
}

Comment: What do you need to do in order to get this exception? Please describe, show your sources, ...

Comment: i added facebook sdk to my project but i always get the error stated above

Answer (score 0):

You might be using different version of sample modules.
Please follow these steps

1. Add multidex in the gradle

   In the module app gradle

   ```
   android {
   ......
       defaultConfig {
       ....
       multiDexEnabled true
   }
   ```
2. Added the dependency

   ```
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
   ```
3. Add the facebook module and exclude dependent libraires

   ```
   compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:$faceBookVersion') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
   }
   ```

Comment: send me the dependencies you have included

Answer (score 0):

If You are using various Google play services like Location, Authentication etc, you should use same level of Libraries.

eg:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.0.1'
```

Comment: im only  using 'com.google.android.gms:play-services wallet :8.4.0'

Comment: Also add MultiDex Enabled in dependency and initialize the the Mutidex in your Application Class